# Python3 32bit 64bit

Tags: python

My computer is 64bit. But I didn't recognize and I installed 32 bit python3.6.
Today morning I installed python3 64bit for my project.
Then I want to use 64 bit one.
How to get rid of python3 32 bit and change to python3 64bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to where you downloaded the installer for the 32-bit version of Python and uninstall it from there.

[image: Just take a look here.]

Then install the 64-bit version. 
It helps when installing to use the manual process.
Install the python version directly into a custom folder of your choosing to the C: drive of your PC. 
Select "add to environment variables" while you are there (this will allow you to run the python console from CMD and PowerShell.

Also tick all these boxes:

[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Python 3 32 bit.  Then check your `system path`.

- Windows:  https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm
- Linux: Set the `$PATH` variable.

Python has a habit of not removing itself from there.

Now make sure the Python 3 64 bit installation is correctly in your `system path`

Comment: Thanks! This was also helpful